# Android - copy remote file to raw folder

Tags: android, xml

How can I copy a remote xml file to my raw folder in order to process it offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make change in raw folder once apk in build........

you have other option

```
1- Internal storage (private are for you app)
2- External Storage (like SD card)
3- Database
```

Comment: correct , and that's not the only folder that cannot be altered at runtime . all of the folders of the apk cannot be changed without root permissions.